# Inserting Result of Time-Consuming Stored Procedures to Tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a website that runs a stored procedure when you open home page. That stored procedure process data from 4 relational table and gives a result. Since DB records increased, completion of the stored procedure can take more than 10 seconds and it is too much for a home page.

So I think, inserting result of the stored procedure into a new table regularly and using that table for home page can be a good idea to solve the problem but I am not sure if it is a good practice for SQL Server.

Is there any better solution for my case?

Edit: Those 4 tables are updated every 15 minutes with about 30 insert.

Comment: One method I've used is to cache a copy of the results in a table along with the date/time the query was run. When a user requests the data the stored procedure checks the age of the cache. If it is acceptable, that's what the user gets, otherwise that user has to wait while the cache is rebuilt. An alternative is a scheduled task that rebuilds the cache at a suitable interval. If done properly there will always be a (somewhat stale) copy of the data available while the new query is running so that no one has to wait for results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to have a "designated victim" update the cache as needed (which may also cause other users to wait) you can do something like this in a stored procedure (SP):

1. Start a transaction to block access to the cache.
2. Check the date/time of the cache entries. (This requires either adding a `CacheUpdated` column to the cache table or storing the value elsewhere.)
3. If the cached data is sufficiently recent then return the data and end the transaction.
4. Delete the cached data and run a new query to refill it with an appropriate `CacheUpdated` date/time.
5. Return the cached data and end the transaction.

If the update time becomes too long for users to wait, or the cache rebuild blocks too many users, you can run a stored procedure at a scheduled interval by creating a *job* in SQL Server Agent. The SP would:

1. Save the current date/time, e.g. as `@Now`.
2. Run the query to update the cache marking each row with `CacheUpdated = @Now`.
3. Delete any cache rows where `CacheUpdate != @Now`.

The corresponding SP for users would simply return the oldest set of data, i.e. `Min( CacheUpdated )` rows. If there is only one set, that's what they get. If an update is in progress then they'll get the older complete set, not the work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you have explained your issue I see no problem in doing that, but you must explain more, since we don't know what type of data you collecting and how it is increases every time, so as to provide you a better solution

Comment: I added update frequency information to the question.

Comment: are you able to  run a stored procedure at a scheduled interval by creating a job in SQL Server Agent, I have discovered that not all of us can use  the SQL Server Agent when using some hosts. Is there a link to your  site so i can tell you my best approach. Because exsits other ways to kill the same cat, and sometimes its just changing the design a littel of you landing page. not the stored procedure.